# msa keeps stopping

Tags: xiaomi, bugs

I have recently this message
"msa keeps stopping"

[image]

Can someone help me to repair the problem . My phone is a mimax3

Comment: There was a buggy update from Chrome. Check the summary/report and see if it's due to `com.google.android.trichromelibrary`.

Comment: After the last update of chrome the bug disappeared